# Do GraphQL queries have to be previously written into .graphql files? Or can I just make them in the code?

Tags: android, graphql

Is it mandatory that I write every single query into .graphql files to be used afterwards in the code? Or can I just simply put the queries somehow in the code itself without any .graphql files?

I've searched a lot and the examples always have the .graphql files, but in a more complex app with a lot of queries it would be nicer to have them in the code rather than in graphql files.

Comment: I haven't touched GraphQL in over a year or so, but as far as I can remember, the ".graphql" is just the _hardcoded_ query, you can always create a string on the fly and send that. I may be wrong now, but I would frown at graphQL if this is not possible. (I frown at GraphQL by default anyway) :)

Comment: That will depend entirely on what you are using to make your GraphQL requests with. Apollo-Android at least used to support dynamic GraphQL requests. "in a more complex app with a lot of queries it would be nicer to have them in the code rather than in graphql files" -- others might disagree with that opinion.

Comment: That is the case...the app I am developing right now is complex and with that in mind I would prefer to have the queries in the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Apollo client for android to consume graphql queries and mutation you have to put your queries and mutation in a **.graphql** files so apollo can build and generate classes for you to consume them. 
[Here is how to apollo client will generate classes for you](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-android#generate-code-using-apollo) 
Also for how to consume the generated classes by apollo client [here](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-android#consuming-code)

I don't recommend to make queries in code because it's a lot of code that no readable and understandable.

Here is how to write queries in code

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/graphql");
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "{\"query\":\"query weather($lat: Float, $lng: Float){\\n  weather(lat: $lat, lng: $lng){\\n    currentTemp\\n    minTemp\\n    maxTemp\\n    icon\\n  }\\n}\",\"variables\":{\"lat\":30.024663,\"lng\":31.485652},\"operationName\":\"weather\"}");
Request request = new Request.Builder()
  .url(BASE_URL)
  .post(body)
  .build();

Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

This is really unreadable and understable code generated by [insomnia](https://insomnia.rest/graphql/)